# Shape corners with negative radius in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a composite view with corners that looks like this:

[image: inset rounded corner]

How it this possible in Android?

Comment: did you find any way?

Comment: @hypd09 look at my answer herehttp://stackoverflow.com/a/24363561/1285670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone have the same problem, best way is use 9.png drawables. In xml it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with using `<vector` in a custom `drawable` file, here `invert_shape.xml`:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:viewportWidth="400"
    android:viewportHeight="400">

    <path
        android:pathData="M3.146,256.500 L3.146,73.449 C41.770,72.388 72.757,41.041 72.757,2.500 L271.500,2.500 L271.500,256.500 L3.146,256.500 Z"
        android:fillColor="#eeffcc"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeWidth="5"/>
</vector>
```

After that you need to set this `drawable` as `android:background` of your `LinearLayout` in your `activity_main.xml` like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/invert_shape"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

**The result:**

[image: inverted corner]

You may asked yourself how to achieve the `android:path` in your `<vector`, I used a simple solution for that. You can use programs like `Photoshop` or `Illustrator` and create your shape there in a `layer`. If you have done that, right click on your `layer` and select "`Copy SVG`". Now you copied the shape, paste it in your `drawable` (here `invert_shape.xml`) in `Android Studio` and you will get parameters like `android:path` and `android:stroke` of your photoshop shape. Get rid of the unnecessary paramteres and make sure you use the right attributes in the `XML` itself. Now, there's no end for your creativity. Cheers! :)

Answer (score -3):

You can able to give the OneSide Corner with set the below frame as background to the layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke 
        android:width="1dip" 
        />
    <solid 
        android:color="#3D2A1D"/>
    <corners 
        android:radius="20sp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

I am not sure with the -ve border radios.

Comment: You didn't understand what I want to do. Maybe because my explanation was bad=) In this picture that green rectangle with one angle cutted is my layout

Comment: @user1285670: Yes i got that. And i have also try it before but not with the inner Round shape corner. My Above code will works with the OneSide outer corner.

Comment: This is not a negative corner its normal corner only.