# Android - how to make inner rounded corner like a paper tag?

Tags: android, android-drawable

[image]

i would like to draw the following image but im confused on how to do the beginning area that i put in orange. i want that to be circular but its a inner circle if you see what i mean from the photo. i tried using a negative radius like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@color/my_green" />
  <corners android:radius="-24dp" />
</shape>
```

but that does not do anything. how is this accomplished ?

p.s it does not have to be in orange can be all the same color i just wanted to emphasis the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used a layer list with two drawables. make a white drawable with circular shape.  just shift that drawables over a bit and ensure its a solid white color. it will give the effect as above.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest. It's the most straightforward way, but it does have the disadvantage of the 'cutout' part not being transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with using `<vector` in a custom `drawable` file, here `invert_shape.xml`:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="359.5"
    android:viewportHeight="196.0">
    <path
        android:pathData="M-0.000,0.000 C108.667,0.000 217.333,0.000 326.000,0.000 C326.000,32.000 326.000,64.000 326.000,96.000 C217.333,96.000 108.667,96.000 -0.000,96.000 C46.617,64.186 37.267,32.149 -0.000,0.000 Z"
        android:fillColor="#2962FF"/>
</vector>
```

After that you need to set this `drawable` as `android:background` of your `LinearLayout` in your `activity_main.xml` like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/invert_shape"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

**The result:**

[image: inverted shape]

You may asked yourself how to achieve the `android:path` in your `<vector`, I used a simple solution for that. You can use programs like `Photoshop` or `Illustrator` and create your shape there in a `layer`. If you have done that, right click on your `layer` and select "`Copy SVG`". Now you copied the shape, paste it in your `drawable` (here `invert_shape.xml`) in `Android Studio` and you will get parameters like `android:path` and `android:stroke` of your photoshop shape. Now, there's no end for your creativity. Cheers! :)

Comment: is there no way to draw it in androids xml instead of vector

Comment: No there is no other way. As you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821253/shape-corners-with-negative-radius-in-android 
I tried a lot and this is the only way to achieve it. Vectors are in XML files also but I know what you mean. But the good thing on that is that your app will stand out if you are creative like the example above. Hope my effort helped you anyways! :)

Comment: what about with the new shapeable api.  https://howtodoandroid.com/shapeableimageview-material-components-android/

Comment: The point is that you can make corners but no inverted corners or edges. In your refrence you only see shapes with cuts or corners. Nothing that needs to be done with a negative value. Hope it helped you and you can understand what I mean? I spent hours with researching for such solutions. This is the only thing I came up with.